# Delete similarly named files in multiple directories

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-search

I have a server directory (windows) that contains somewhere around 25000 files in 3000 folders.

At some point in the past a program has gone through and added a file called .xconfig to almost all of the directories.

I'd like to delete these files as they are unnecessary and tend to confuse people when they are looking for actual config files.

Windows does not recognise these files in its search "feature" so I was wondering if there was another way to search for and delete these files - command line maybe?

Comment: in windows you might try specifying it as .filename. - windows sees it as an extension without a filename. dos should see it fine. In windows you can use pretty much any other explorer replacement as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `del` from the command line:

```
del /s .xconfig
```

The `/s` switch instructs `del` to recurse into all subdirectories. Execute the command with the working directory set to the top level directory which contains these files.

You are having no luck from the Explorer shell because it does not regard such a file (no name, only an extension) as being valid. But `del` is quite happy to delete such files.